# Sharepoint search button customization

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-branding

I am working on SharePoint Branding project, where i need to change the whole sharepoint look and feel according to Clients design guidelines/Visual Designs.

happy part, most of the branding is done but still i am facing problem with SEARCH BUTTON of sharepoint. Ia m not able to replace this default button with my designed button.

any direction ll be great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did was replace the delegate control of the search button with our own, using a feature. In that feature we specified our custom image for the button.

Comment: thanks Vladi, even i am thinking this is the only solution for it :(. I have tried different blogs and articles but not getting any specific answer for this.. here are two links .. http://padavis.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/sharepoint-search-button-hover-problem/
http://aarebrot.net/blog/2008/06/blueband-master-how-to-fix-that-broken-search-button/

but when i m trying this my Sharepoint is giving error.

Comment: Create a feature similar to this OSearchEnhancedFeature, just change the images in SearchArea.xml and make sure to set sequence to number lower than 25

Answer (score 0):

This might help - http://labs.steveottenad.com/reskin-restyle-a-sharepoint-2010-search-box/

When we customised the search box we hide the default img for the search button using css and replaced it with a new background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace the default button with you own search button. You can however customize it to your needs using CSS styles. I have done the same thing. You can create your custom style to override the styles from the corev15.css file.

Create you custom styles css file, reference it in your page layout and just use it.

Hope that helps.